# Redirect non-www to www using php header() function

Tags: php

I want to redirect non-www url to www using php.

I know it can easily be achived by using mod_rewrite in htaccess. But I would like to do this redirection using php header().

I have written a script that checks if the host is with or without www.

```
  $url=$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
if(preg_match_all("/http:\/\/www\./i",$url,$m))
{echo "host has www";}
```

else
    {echo "host not starting with www";}

How can I go ahead with it and  add a header with 301 status to redirect it to www.domain.com if the orignal host is non-www ?

Is this kind of redirection possible in php?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'www') === false) {
    $protocol = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && filter_var($_SERVER['HTTPS'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)
        ? 'https'
        : 'http';
    header(
        "Location: $protocol://www." . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
        true,
        301
    );
}
```

Comment: Is this 302 redirect?

Comment: You can put any `http_response_code` as the third parameter of the header function

Comment: Ok and what is with SSL? ;)

Comment: I've updated my answer. Though was not absolutely necessarily because I think he knows which protocol is using, but it is a good practice to put it for future possible users with the same question.

Answer (score 2):

`header('Location: http://www.YOURDOMAIN.com/foo/bar?foo=bar', true, 301);`

Check it out [here](http://php.net/manual/de/function.header.php).

Comment: Thanks, How will I add perameters to the target url?

Comment: What do you mean? The path `../foo/bar` or some querystring `?foo=bar` just append it to the url.

Comment: I have got a working answer, thank you too for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You check the REFERER not the hostname.

```
$protocol = (@$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://";

if (substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, 4) !== 'www.') {
    header('Location: ' . $protocol.'www.' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], true, 301);
    exit;
}
```

Something like this.

Comment: Good answer, also consider the difference between a 301 & 302 redirect which can be set in the 3rd parameter of the header command.

Comment: Undefined index "https"

Comment: HTTPS is not set on every request so i have updated the code.